# ORA-00904 error when data exist

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I use code as below to check if code exists, if there is no the same code, executeQuery() is no any problems.

```
public boolean isExist(String code) throws DataBaseException {
    boolean isExist = false;

    StringBuffer querySql = new StringBuffer();
    querySql.append(" SELECT ");
    querySql.append(" MY_CODE ");
    querySql.append(" FROM ");
    querySql.append(" MY_MST ");
    querySql.append(" WHERE ");
    querySql.append(" MY_CODE = ? ");

    try {
        super.setQuerySql(querySql.toString());
        super.addParameter(Types.VARCHAR, code);
        List<Object> resultsList = super.executeQuery();

        if (resultsList != null && resultsList.size() > 0) {
            isPsiExist = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DataBaseException(e, "Can't get the code.", this.getClass().getName(), querySql.toString());
    }

    return isExist;
}
```

But if the code exists, then ORA-00904 happened, does anyone tell me why? How can I solve this issue?

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [ SELECT  MY_CODE  FROM  MY_MST  WHERE  MY_CODE = ? ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: invalid identifier.
```

Comment: Your super class apparently doesn't deal with parameters correctly, since it literally executes the query `SELECT  MY_CODE  FROM  MY_MST  WHERE  MY_CODE = ?`.

Comment: super.addParameter is NG? but when I use the same way to INSERT, it is no any problems...

Comment: I don't know what NG means. If you want help, post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about how to use a prepared statement in JDBC, though your attempt to use a prepared statement is definitely on the right track.  You should use the following pattern:

```
String sql = "SELECT CODE FROM MY_MST WHERE CODE = ?";
try {
    PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, code);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
       // process the current row
    }
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem use your own class for the `PreparedStatement` :

```
super.setQuerySql(querySql.toString());
super.addParameter(Types.VARCHAR, code);
List<Object> resultsList = super.executeQuery();
```

The problem is

```
super.addParameter(Types.VARCHAR, code);
```

It doesn't set the parameter.

But as you don't show it, it is not easy to give a more specific answer.

Anyway, don't try to reinvent the things that work. Use a `PreparedStatement` that does the job. 
If really useful, you can use a wrapper class that contains it but rely essentially on it to do your queries and exploit their results.

Answer (score 0):

I found reason for error, because my mapRow method used multiple columns, sorry to trouble you.

```
protected Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNumber) throws SQLException {
    ...
    psi.setCode(resultSet.getString("MY_CODE"));
    psi.setName(resultSet.getString("NAME"));
    ...
}
```

Now it is ok after I modified as below

```
protected Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNumber) throws SQLException {
    ...
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int count = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    if (count == 1) {
        psi.setCode(resultSet.getString("MY_CODE"));
    }
    else {
        psi.setCode(resultSet.getString("MY_CODE"));
        psi.setName(resultSet.getString("NAME"));
    }
}
```